# Please help me understand decorators in Python (Fibonnacci + memoization)

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to understand the following code (from this website: http://jeremykun.com/2012/01/12/a-spoonful-of-python/):

```
def memoize(f):
    cache = {}

    def memoizedFunction(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]

    memoizedFunction.cache = cache  
    return memoizedFunction 

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n <= 2:
          return 1
    else:
          return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

I understand the benefit of having a cache, esp for something like calculating Fibonacci numbers. I also understand that now when I call fib(4), it is equivalent to calling myfun(4), where myfun = memoize(fib).

What I don't understand is why cache is not reassigned to {} for each call of fib.

Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand why `cache` would not be reassigned in the case of calling `myfun(4)`, but is instead assigned when calling `myfunc = memoize(fib)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decorator `memoize` is only called once, when `fib` is defined.  The `cache` is stored in a closure (representing the local variables of `memoize`) which every call to `fib` has access to.  Every subsequent call to `fib` results in a call to `memoizedFunction`, not a call to `memoize`, and since neither `fib` nor `memoizedFunction` resets the cache, it never gets reset.

Comment: Also, just to double check, the line "memoized_function.cache = cache" is not necessary, correct?  "cache" will still be visible to all subsequent calls to "memoizedFunction()" without this line.

Comment: @monkeybiz7: Yes, that's true.  (I didn't even notice that line.)